# How to Convert HTML to PDF Using PHP?

Tags: software

PDF or Portable Document Format is a popular file type that is often used for online documents. It's great for distributing downloadable written content, and is frequently used by governments and businesses alike. Because it's a format that's familiar to all, many applications allow the user to convert other document types to the PDF format. PHP is one programming language that has a built-in ability to convert to PDF. PHP scripts can be used to transform file types such as HTML into PDF files.

Answer (score 3):

Try [dompdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), it looks like what you need:

> dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter. At its heart, dompdf is (mostly) CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout and rendering engine written in PHP. It is a style-driven renderer: it will download and read external stylesheets, inline style tags, and the style attributes of individual HTML elements. It also supports most presentational HTML attributes.

Also, one of the answers for [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597348/1071869) suggests [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/):

> Simple shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine, and qt.

So your PHP code could call it. However, has some problems:

- It needs a patched Qt for some features
- It needs the X.org stack in the server-side

Or you could combine [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) (HTML to PostScript) and [ps2pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/AFPL/6.50/Ps2pdf.htm) (PostScript to PDF).